# Algorithm to count number of nodes in an AVL tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, pseudocode, avl-tree

> Assume the following notation/operations on AVL trees. An empty AVL tree is denoted E. A
>   non-empty AVL tree T has three attributes:
>
> • The key T.key is the root node’s key.
>
> • The left child T.left is T’s left subtree, which is an AVL tree (possibly E).
>
> • The right child T.right is T’s right subtree, which is an AVL tree (possibly E).

I'm trying to write an algorithm (pseudocode would do) Count(T, lo, hi) that counts and returns the number of nodes in an AVL tree with root T, where the key value is in the range lo ≤ key ≤ hi. I want it to have time complexity O(n) where n is the number of nodes in the AVL tree T. One idea I had was recursion but this didn't seem to have the required complexity. Any ideas?

Comment: You left out a key fact: What is n? This problem is trivial if n is the number of nodes in the tree. It's a bit harder of n is the resulting count. A recursive tree traversal requires only constant time per node visited. Why do you think its performance isn't good enough?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question. n is the former. Is there some sort of ready-made code online for these? I would assume there is but I can't seem to find one

Comment: I'm sure your homework is not meant to be solved by copying posted code. Just traverse the tree and count nodes with values in the desired range, ignoring the rest. The fact that it's an AVL tree doesn't make traversing it any different from traversing any binary tree. So you can begin by studying up on binary tree traversal.

Comment: Recursion is fine as long as each node is visited once. An [in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_(LNR)) should do the trick. Start counting when the traversal finds a key ≥ lo. Stop counting (and stop the traversal) when the traversal finds a key > hi.

Comment: If the tree _really_ is AVL, it must be balanced. This seems to be the key fact to help you save the problem faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a global variable like counter, iterate the tree with [Pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order_(NLR))  this has a cost of (n+e) and add 1 for each node.

You can add a counter too, and when add a new node inside the data structure, you can add 1, and if you remove a node you can subtract 1